# Transforming a CSV from wide to long format

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have a csv like this:

```
col1,col2,col2_val,col3,col3_val
A,1,3,5,6
B,2,3,4,5
```

and i want to transfer this csv like this :

```
col1,col6,col7,col8
A,Col2,1,3
A,col3,5,6
```

there are col3 and col3_val so i want to keep col3 in col6 and values of col3 in col7 and col3_val's value in col8 in the same row where col3's value is stored.

Comment: Totally unclear what you want... Also please show what you've tried.

Comment: I have updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is `df.melt` and `df.groupby`:

```
In [63]: df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.strip('_val')).melt('col1')\
           .groupby(['col1', 'variable'], as_index=False)['value'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.values))\
           .add_prefix('value')\
           .reset_index()
Out[63]: 
  col1 variable  value0  value1
0    A     col2       1       3
1    A     col3       5       6
2    B     col2       2       3
3    B     col3       4       5
```

<sub>Credit to [John Galt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45832524/4909087) for help with the second part.</sub>

If you wish to rename columns, assign the whole expression above to `df_out` and then do:

```
df_out.columns = ['col1', 'col6', 'col7', 'col8']
```

Saving this should be straightforward with `df.to_csv`.

Comment: @KNp Fixed. How is it now?

Comment: @KNp assuming pandas version is the same, I think yes.