# Reshaping a melted pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to reshape a melted dataframe from another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45831857/transforming-from-wide-to-long-format-csv-using-pandas). As of now, this is what I have:

```
    col1  variable  value
0    A     col2      1
1    B     col2      2
2    A     col2      3
3    B     col2      3
4    A     col3      5
5    B     col3      4
6    A     col3      6
7    B     col3      5
```

I'm trying to get it to something like:

```
  col1 variable value1 value2
0    A     col2   1    3
1    A     col3   5    6 
2    B     col2   2    3
3    B     col3   4    5
```

To understand the logic behind this reordering, this is what the original dataframe looks like, sorted:

```
  col1 variable  value
0    A     col2      1 \   1 (value1 = 1, value2 = 3)
2    A     col2      3 /
4    A     col3      5 \   2 (value1 = 5, value2 = 6)
6    A     col3      6 /
1    B     col2      2 \   3 (value1 = 2, value2 = 3)
3    B     col2      3 /
5    B     col3      4 \   4 (value1 = 4, value2 = 5)
7    B     col3      5 /
```

What I want to do is something like a reshape.

I believe this would have something to do with `pivot` or `pivot_table`, but I'm not sure... How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way using `groupby`

```
In [589]: (df.groupby(['col1', 'variable']).value.apply(list)
             .apply(pd.Series)
             .rename(columns=lambda x: 'value{}'.format(x+1))
             .reset_index())
Out[589]:
  col1 variable  value1  value2
0    A     col2       1       3
1    A     col3       5       6
2    B     col2       2       3
3    B     col3       4       5
```

Comment: I've gone with `df.groupby(['col1', 'variable'], as_index=False)['value'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.values))` but this will do it nicely. Thanks!